# Undefined property: MongoDB\Driver\Manager::$db

Tags: php, mongodb, wamp

I have a local MongoDB database running on WAMP on Windows 10. I'm using PHP version 7.2.10, Apache 2.4.35, and MongoDB extension 1.5.3. I have a pretty simple web application that I'm testing, and when I try to send data to my database via a php script, I get this error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: MongoDB\Driver\Manager::$db in 
C:\wamp64\www\php\test.php
```

Relevant parts of `test.php`, the file in question, look like this:

```
$objectId = new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId();
$dbhost = "127.0.0.1:27017";
$dbname = "db";
$m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
var_dump($m);
$db = $m->$dbname;
```

The property being undefined results in another error: `Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function selectCollection() on null` which causes the script to fail.

What is causing the property `MongoDB\Driver\Manager::$db` to be undefined?

Comment: use `MongoDB\Client` instead of `MongoDB\Driver\Manager`

Comment: @Kazz yep, that's what I thought as well. Throws `Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'MongoDB\Client' not found`

Comment: your code the `$m->$dbname` also the `->selectCollection(...)` correspond to legacy mongo but `MongoDB\Driver\Manager` is part of newer mongodb so you have mismatch of two different libs in your code, see: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php (legacy) and http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php

Comment: @Kazz thanks so much, that's defo what I was missing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Working php code looks such as the following. Please, pay attention to the presence a link to **'vendor/autoload.php'**:

```
  $DB_CONNECTION_STRING="mongodb://YourCredentials";
  require '../../vendor/autoload.php';
  $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager( $DB_CONNECTION_STRING );
```

Then if you use MongoDB\Driver\Manager, a modern version of MongoDB driver, your CRUD operations will look such as this:

***Create** a document in the collection*:

```
$bulkWrite = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$doc = ['name' => 'John', age => 33, profession => 'Guess what?'];
$bulkWrite->insert($doc);
$manager->executeBulkWrite('db.MyCollection', $bulkWrite);
```

***Read** document in the collection* by name with a limit:

```
$filter = ['name' => 'John'];
$options = ['limit' => 2];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$manager->executeQuery('db.MyCollection', $query);
```

***Read** document in the collection* by MongoDb _id with a limit:

```
$filter = ['_id' => new MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID( '5bdf54e6d722dc000f0aa6c2' )];
$options = ['limit' => 2];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$manager->executeQuery('db.MyCollection', $query);
```

***Update** document in the collection*:  (Read more about options upsert and multi [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-bulkwrite.update.php))

```
$bulkWrite = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$filter = ['name' => 'John'];
$update = ['$set' => ['name' => 'Smith', age: 35, profession => 'Guess what?']];
$options = ['multi' => false, 'upsert' => false];
$bulkWrite->update($filter, $update, $options);
$manager->executeBulkWrite('db.MyCollection', $bulkWrite);
```

***Delete** document in the collection - Delete*:

```
$bulkWrite = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$filter = ['name' => 'John', age => 35];
$options = ['limit' => 1];
$bulkWrite->delete($filter, $options);
$manager->executeBulkWrite('db.MyCollection', $bulkWrite);
```

Comment: How do you use $manager to list content of collection media?
In Mongo shell this works  `db.media.find()`  Thank you. While `new MongoDB\Driver\Manager( $DB_CONNECTION_STRING );` seem to resolve to an object however `new MongoDB\Client( $DB_CONNECTION_STRING );` does not