# MongoDB PHP Error: Warning: Undefined property: MongoDB\Driver\Manager

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to use MongoDB on my local machine using the advice in [this stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53019846/undefined-property-mongodb-driver-managerdb). I'm using XAMPP on Windows 10, php version 8.01, and MongoDB extension 1.9.0.

It's a very basic script that connects to MongoDB and tries to use one of the databases.

But I am still getting this warning:

```
Connection to database successfully
Warning: Undefined property: MongoDB\Driver\Manager::$aws_inventories in C:\xampp\htdocs\mongo_connect.php on line 8
```

This is my code:

```
<?php
   require 'C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\autoload.php'; // include Composer's autoloader
   $DB_CONNECTION_STRING="mongodb://localhost:27017";
   // connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager( $DB_CONNECTION_STRING );
   echo "Connection to database successfully";
   // select a database
   $db = $m->aws_inventories;
?>
```

How can I get rid of the warning and connect to the DB correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're trying to access a property which doesn't exists in `MongoDB\Driver\Manager` class object.

Second, `$db = $m->aws_inventories;` works with `MongoDB\Client` library.

Here are few example to get collections list or find all/specific document/s or insert/bulk insert, update a document or to perform a distinct query

Get all collections of aws_inventories:

```php
try {
    $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
    $command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(["listCollections" => 1]);
    
    $cursor = $manager->executeCommand("aws_inventories", $command);
    
    // list of all collections in aws_inventories
    $collections = $cursor->toArray();
    
    var_dump($collections);
} catch (\MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {
}
```

Get all documents from a collection:

```php
try {
    $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
    
    // setting options and filter
    $filter  = [];
    $options = [];
    
    /*
    // or to find specific documents based on a condition and limit records
    $filter  = [
        'service' => 'ec2',
        'instance' => 'co',
        'type' => 'c5',
        'vCPU' => [
            '$gt' => 2
        ]
    ];
    
    $options = [
        'limit' => 10,
        'maxTimeMS' => 1000,    // to limit the execution time of a query
        'sort' => [
            'vCPU' => -1
        ]
    ];
    */
    
    // constructing the query
    $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
    
    $cursor = $manager->executeQuery('aws_inventories.test', $query);
    
    foreach ($cursor as $document) {
        var_dump($document);
    }
} catch (\MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {
}
```

To perform distinct query:

```php
try {
    $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
    
    $query = [
        'size' => '2xlarge'
    ];
    $command = new MongoDB\Driver\Command([
        'distinct' => 'test',   // Collection name
        'key' => 'instance',    // field for which we want to get distinct values
        'query' => $query       // criteria to filter documents
    ]);
        
    $cursor = $manager->executeCommand("aws_inventories", $command);
    
    // to get distinct values as array
    $instances = current($cursor->toArray())->values;
    
    var_dump($instances);
} catch (\MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {
}
```

To insert single/multiple document/s:

```php
try {
    $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
    $bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;

    $bulk->insert([
        'service' => 'ec2',
        'instance' => 'co',
        'type' => 'c5',
        'size' => 'large',
        'model' => 'c5.large',
        'vCPU' => 2,
        'memory' => 4,
        'storage' => 'ebs-only',
        'network_bandwidth' => 10,
        'ebs_bandwidth' => 4750  
    ]);
    
    $bulk->insert([
        'service' => 'ec2',
        'instance' => 'gp',
        'type' => 't3',
        'size' => 'nano',
        'model' => 't3.nano',
        'vCPU' => 2,
        'memory' => 0.5,
        'storage' => 'ebs-only',
        'network_bandwidth' => 5 
    ]);
    
    $result = $manager->executeBulkWrite('aws_inventories.test', $bulk);
    
} catch (\MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {
}
```

To update existing document/s: (Taken from [executeUpdate](https://php.uz/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.executeupdate.php) example)

```php
try {
    $manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
    $criteria = [
        'service' => 'ec2',
        'type' => 'c5'
    ];
    
    $document = [
        '$set' => [
            'features' => [
                'Powered by the AWS Nitro System, a combination of dedicated hardware and lightweight hypervisor'
            ]           
        ]       
    ];

    $updateOptions = array(
        'multi' => true,    // false - to update only first matching document, true - update all matching documents
        'upsert' => 0
    );
    
    $writeConcern = new MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern(MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern::MAJORITY, 100);

    $result = $manager->executeUpdate('aws_inventories.test', $criteria, $document, $updateOptions, $writeConcern);
    
    printf("Updated %d document(s)\n", $result->getModifiedCount());
    printf("Matched %d document(s)\n", $result->getMatchedCount());
    printf("Upserted documents: %d\n", $result->getUpsertedCount());
    foreach ($result->getUpsertedIds() as $index => $id) {
        printf("upsertedId[%d]: ", $index);
        var_dump($id);
    }
    
    /* If the WriteConcern could not be fulfilled */
    if ($writeConcernError = $result->getWriteConcernError()) {
        printf("%s (%d): %s\n", $error->getMessage(), $error->getCode(), var_export($error->getInfo(), true));
    }
    
    /* If the write could not happen at all */
    foreach ($result->getWriteErrors() as $writeError) {
        printf("%s (%d)\n", $error->getMessage(), $error->getCode());
    }
} catch (\MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$m->aws_inventories` That looks like as the older/deprecated approach. Could you try to follow this tutorial?

https://zetcode.com/db/mongodbphp/

```php
<?php

try {

    $mng = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");

    $stats = new MongoDB\Driver\Command(["dbstats" => 1]);
    $res = $mng->executeCommand("aws_inventories", $stats);
    
    $stats = current($res->toArray());

    print_r($stats);

} catch (MongoDB\Driver\Exception\Exception $e) {

    $filename = basename(__FILE__);
    
    echo "The $filename script has experienced an error.\n"; 
    echo "It failed with the following exception:\n";
    
    echo "Exception:", $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    echo "In file:", $e->getFile(), "\n";
    echo "On line:", $e->getLine(), "\n";       
}
    
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This example is adapted from the official doc https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.executequery.php

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$db = 'test_database';
$col = 'mycol';
$namespace = $db.'.'.$col;

// insert data
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$bulk->insert(['x' => 1]);
$bulk->insert(['x' => 2]);
$bulk->insert(['x' => 3]);
$manager->executeBulkWrite($namespace, $bulk);

// query
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query(['x' => ['$gt' => 1]], []);
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery($namespace, $query);

foreach ($cursor as $document) {
    var_dump($document);
}
```

As the document suggests, [MongoDB\Driver\Manager](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php) is a generic abstraction to manage any type of MongoDB connection (standalone server, replica set, or sharded cluster) so the methods will look a bit too complicated for simple CRUD on standalone server.

If you just want to connect to a standalone server, you may want to check [MongoDB\Client](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.tutorial.library.php). Here is the code that do exactly the same thing:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$col = $client->test_database->mycol;

// insert data
$col->insertMany([
    ['x' => 1],
    ['x' => 2],
    ['x' => 3],
]);

// query
$docs = $col->find(['x' => ['$gt' => 1]]);
foreach ($docs as $document) {
    var_dump($document);
}
```